# Running python app in the background on linux

Tags: linux, ssh, python, terminal, background-process

Weird question here, but I'm playing with a python chat server/client combo on my Linux server. Currently, if I do this:

```
$: cd /path/to/chat/server
$: sudo python ChatServer_Listen.py
```

This starts the python app run loop and the server listens for incoming TCP connections.

My problem is, if I close my terminal window, the ssh session quits and the python app stops running, and clients can no longer connect.  I'd rather not run a terminal instance 24/7 locally. Can I set up this python app as something that can run in the background on Linux? If so, how? Ideally it would be sort of like Apache which just runs as a service.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Did you try `nohup python ChatServer_Listen.py &` ? It should work.

Comment: Same as any other *nix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525188/linux-running-process-background The & is the most important part.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with EC2.

Comment: It worked, gents, someone please make an official answer =) Follow up, with the process detached, how do I kill/stop or restart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `nohup python ChatServer_Listen.py &`

`nohup` will log your program output to `nohup.out` file.

To stop your program you have to use `kill your_pid` command.

Comment: This works for me, I thought it didn't but then I realized that I wasn't including the & character.  Will this keep the program running indefinitely (until a reboot, crash or explicit kill of course)

Comment: @JustinXXVII Yes of course

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).  It's made exactly for this purpose, plus it will do things like restart the process if it dies, provide a web-based GUI to control it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to keep a process alive after you log off is to use [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

Comment: When I try this, sudo screen python Chatserver_Listen.py, the next line says "[screen is terminating]". The python app begins as normal, but using another terminal instance and "sudo screen -r python" returns "There is no screen to be resumed matching python."

Answer (score 1):

Like explained here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup

"

Using the Job Control of bash to send the process into the background:

> [crtl]+z
>
> bg

And as Sam/Jan mentioned you have to execute disown to avoid killing the process after you close the terminal.

> disown -h

"

Comment: This is what works for me. Can you explain the disown -h command and what it actually does? My flowchart was like this: 1) run python app, 2) press ctrl+z [app is suspended?],3) type bg [console prints something regarding python], 4) type disown -h [console prints nothing].  It seems to be working though, I closed the terminal window and the server is still listening and accepting clients

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to change the code to daemonize the process correctly. One way to do this is to use the `daeminize` module.

The expedient way to do this, which also works with software that you cannot modify, is to start it like this

```
nohup python ChatServer_Listen.py >logfile.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

Note that I didn't use `sudo`. That is because you should put the above line in a shell script and run the shell script with sudo.